# Touchpad reverse scroll settings resets upon reboot

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, touchpad

Lubuntu 14.04, LXDE.

`echo "pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12" > ~/.Xmodmap && xmodmap .Xmodmap` works, but will reset upon reboot. How to make this permanent?

Same issue with horizontal scrolling. `synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1` works, but will reset upon reboot.

Can anyone help with making these permanent? I'm unsure of how to use the startup functions on Lubuntu.

I have attempted to go to ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart and insert the above functions, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you wrote a script or simply added the "functions" ?

script example

```
#!/bin/bash
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
```

The ubuntu user forum says (since Version 13.10)

You have to go to

```
Startmenu -> Settings -> Default applications for LXSession -> Autostart
```

and add your **script** here. (By typing your path to the script in the textbox and click add ("Hinzufügen") )

[image]

**Alternative:**

Add your **script** here

```
 ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/autostart#Lubuntu-LXDE (in german)

Comment: So the syntax for a script should be like`#!/bin/bash@synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
@syndaemon -d -t
echo "pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12" > ~/.Xmodmap && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` and then put in the autostart folder? does it execute then?

Comment: Also, how do I actually add it in the default applications? It just tells me to write something, but just writing "touchpad.sh" won't exactly have the pathing for it?

Comment: I think you have to type the absolute path (e.g. /home/[username]/directory/scrip.sh).  I guess it doesn't matter where the script is, when you add it through the interface. Why did you add a '@' in the syntax ?